# Adding Custom Node Module and use it in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use a 3rd party Javascript library for plotting within my Angular application. However, I have some VPN issues that will take a while to resolve and in the meantime, I have been presented with the javascript min.js and min.js.map files.

Is there a way I can manually add these two files into my Node_Modules directory and import them into my Angular application to use without having to do 'npm install'?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding them in the scripts array in angular.json or add them in the index.html file using the script tag, like this:

```
<script src="fileName.min.js"></script>
```